# Determining a matrix representation of a linear transformation relative to a basis

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

T: $R^4$ to P2 defined by T(a1, a2, a3, a4)=(a1+a2)+(a2+a3)x+(a3+a4)$x^2$

B={ (1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,0), (1,1,0,0), (1,0,0,0) }

C=( 1, 1+x, 1+$x^2$ )

**Question**: **Find the matrix representation relative to the basis B and basis C**

Attempt:

T(1,1,1,1)=2+2x+2$x^2$=a(1,1,1,1)+b(1,1,1,0)+c(1,1,0,0)+d(1,0,0,0)

T(1,1,1,0)=2+2x+$x^2$=a(1,1,1,1)+b(1,1,1,0)+c(1,1,0,0)+d(1,0,0,0)

T(1,1,0,0)=2+x=a(1,1,1,1)+b(1,1,1,0)+c(1,1,0,0)+d(1,0,0,0)

T(1,0,0,0)=1=a(1,1,1,1)+b(1,1,1,0)+c(1,1,0,0)+d(1,0,0,0)

After solving for a,b,c,d I get the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -1 & 1\\ 2 & 2 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Where is $x$ defined?  How can you have a quadratic term in a linear transformation?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Am I missing something here? The question is in bold. I just want to know if its right.

Comment: A linear transformation from a 4-dimensional vector space to a 3-dimensional space will have a $3\times4$ matrix, not a $3\times3$.

Comment: To get you started: $2+2x+2x^2=(-2)(1)+(2)(1+x)+(2)(1+x^2)$ So your first column is certainly correct. You have just left out the 4th column.

Comment: So, can you get the full answer now, Essie?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: I havent abandoned my question, I just forgot I asked about it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should express the results of your four transformations in terms of the ordered basis $\mathscr C,$ not $\mathscr B$ (it appears that you did that to get a partially-correct answer, but your attempt suggests some incomplete understanding):
$$\begin{align}
T(1,1,1,1) & = 2 + 2x + 2x^2\\
           & = -2(1) + 2(1+x) + 2(1+x^2)\\\\
T(1,1,1,0) & = 2 + 2x +  x^2\\
           & = -1(1) + 2(1+x) + 1(1+x^2)\\\\
T(1,1,0,0) & = 2 + x\\
           & =  1(1) + 1(1+x) + 0(1+x^2)\\\\
T(1,0,0,0) & = 1\\
           & =  1(1) + 0(1+x) + 0(1+x^2).\end{align}$$
The coefficients of the elements of $\mathscr C$ are the columns of the matrix of $T$ relative to $\mathscr B$ and $\mathscr C:$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
 2 &  2 & 1 & 0\\
 2 &  1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$